# VBA and Json POST MS Access

Tags: json, vba, ms-access, post

To work with an api I want to make a Post in VBA. The post itself works, but a structured body for Json in the request does not work for me. how do you get this data structured in a VBA (Access)
The VBA below is used for the post, the data in the 'sEnv' var should be structured in a other format. But How?

```vb
    Sub confirm()
        Dim sMsg As String
        Dim sURL As String
        Dim sEnv As String
        Dim body As New Dictionary
               
        BC = ""
        response = ""

        'Set and Instantiate our working objects
        Set barcode_info = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60

        C_num = CUST_NUMBER
        C_code = CUST_CODE
        Key = API_KEY
                
        sEnv = "
                {
                  "Customer": {
                    "Address": {
                      "AddressType": "02",
                      "City": "Hoofddorp",
                      "CompanyName": "PostNL",
                      "Countrycode": "NL",
                      "HouseNr": "42",
                      "Street": "Siriusdreef",
                      "Zipcode": "2132WT"
                    },
                    "CollectionLocation": "1234506",
                    "ContactPerson": "Janssen",
                    "CustomerCode": "ABZL",
                    "CustomerNumber": "9005728",
                    "Email": "email@company.com",
                    "Name": "Janssen"
                  },
                  "Message": {
                    "MessageID": "1",
                    "MessageTimeStamp": "29-06-2016 12:00:00",
                    "Printertype": "GraphicFile|PDF"
                  }}""
            
               
                
       sURL = "https://api-sandbox.postnl.nl/shipment/v2/confirm"
                
       barcode_info.Open "POST", sURL, False
       barcode_info.setRequestHeader "accept","application/json"
       barcode_info.setRequestHeader "apikey", Key
       barcode_info.send (sEnv)
                
       response = barcode.responseText
       'Debug.Print objhttp.responseText("barcode")
                
       Set response = JsonConverter.ParseJson(barcode.responseText)
               
       BC = response("Barcode", "Warnings")
       MsgBox (BC)
            
       'MsgBox (response("Barcode"))
       'barcodes_ophalen = response("Barcode")
            
       'clean up code
       Set barcode = Nothing
       Set xmlDoc = Nothing
       Set response = Nothing
                        
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off pasting your JSON into a worksheet cell and reading it from there.

Otherwise it's a mess of quotes:

```vb
senv = "{""Customer"": {" & _
          """Address"": {" & _
            """AddressType"": ""02""," & _
            """City"": ""Hoofddorp""," & _
            """CompanyName"": ""PostNL""," & _
            """Countrycode"": ""NL""," & _
            """HouseNr"": ""42""," & _
            """Street"": ""Siriusdreef""," & _
           """Zipcode"": ""2132WT""" & _
          "}," & _
          """CollectionLocation"": ""1234506""," & _
          """ContactPerson"": ""Janssen""," & _
          """CustomerCode"": ""ABZL""," & _
          """CustomerNumber"": ""9005728""," & _
          """Email"": ""email@company.com""," & _
          """Name"": ""Janssen""" & _
        "}," & _
        """Message"": {" & _
          """MessageID"": ""1""," & _
          """MessageTimeStamp"": ""29-06-2016 12:00:00""," & _
          """Printertype"": ""GraphicFile|PDF""" & _
        "}}"""
```